# Lotus Notes - How to read out checkbox values in formula language

Tags: checkbox, boolean, field, lotus-notes

I am working on an XML export for Lotus Notes.
I got the following form field:

[image: Form Lotus Notes]

Now, I want to read out the field value, using the following formula:

```
@If(ap_BewerbungEingegangen=@True;@Text(1);@Text(0))
```

This returns 0 when it should clearly return 1, why is this the case?
Anyone got an idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notes doesn't save the checkbox's value as boolean. In your case the value might be "Bewerbung eingegangen" if it is checked and "" if not. As you have only one value that can be checked or not, your formula can look like this:

```
@If(ap_BewerbungEingegangen != ""; "1"; "0")
```

In general, a checkbox can have several entries and it is possible to define aliases for the values. You can check the field properties in form.